# Start a jQuery function after x pixel scroll

Tags: jquery, function, scroll

I have a jQuery function that I would like to start only after the user has scroll down a certain amount of pixels. Here are my functions :

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mw73enz8/10/)

```
<script>
$(function() {

    var width = $('img').width();
    var height = $('img').height();

    $('img').width(0).height(0);

    var ratio = width/height;

    console.log(width,height);


$(window).on("scroll", function() {

    console.log(ratio);
    var w = $(document).scrollTop();

    $("img").width(w*ratio).height(w)
});

});
</script>
```

I tried to wrap it into that function to have:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {

    scrollPosition = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (scrollPosition >= 500) {

        // If the function is only supposed to fire once
        $(this).off('scroll');

    $(function() {
        var width = $('img').width();
        var height = $('img').height();

        $('img').width(0).height(0);

        var ratio = width/height;

        console.log(width,height);


    $(window).on("scroll", function() {

        console.log(ratio);
        var w = $(document).scrollTop();    
            $("img").width(w*ratio).height(w)
    });        
    });
    }
});
```

Thing is I need it to start after 500px scrolled and first appear at zero width and height. Maximum width would be 151px, maximum height 500px. The idea is to have a kind of zoom in effect.

But no success...

Anybody with any highlight? It will be wonderful, thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the most minimalistic approach I could think of using the current code, taking into account the requirements - start scaling above 500 pixels scrolled up to a maximum of 500 pixels image height :

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoWMKg?editors=001)

```
$(function() {

var img = $('img'),
width = img.width(),
height = img.height(),
ratio = width/height;

img.width(0).height(0);

$(window).scroll(function() {

    var current = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (current > 500) {

    var term = Math.min(current-500, 500),
    range = term*ratio;

    img.width(range).height(term);
    }
    else img.width(0).height(0);
});
});
```

Seems to do the trick but I might be tempted to write an optimised version, using a `transform` and `requestAnimationFrame`. This could be a nice improvement, especially if there are more animations happening on the page. Stand alone, this shouldn't have a huge impact on performance though.

---

Update - here's the full approach that I would take... all it needs is for two variables to be defined at the top - `startpoint` for the scroll position the zoom should start at and `maxheight` for the largest size the image should become. The rest will be calculated automatically, with some optimisation tweaks :

[**Pen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Zbewry?editors=001)

```
$(window).on('load', function() {

var startpoint = 500,
maxheight = 500,
img = $('img'),
apex = img.height(),
scale = maxheight/apex,
modern = window.requestAnimationFrame;

img.css('transform-origin', '0 0');
scaleIt(0);

$(this).scroll(function() {

    var current = $(this).scrollTop(),
    active = img.hasClass('zoomed');

    if (current > startpoint && current <= startpoint+maxheight) {
    if (!active) img.addClass('zoomed');

    var ratio = (current-startpoint)/maxheight*scale;

    if (modern) requestAnimationFrame(function() {scaleIt(ratio)});
    else scaleIt(ratio);
    }
    else if (current <= startpoint && active) {
    scaleIt(0);
    img.removeClass('zoomed');
    }
    else if (active) {
    scaleIt(scale);
    img.removeClass('zoomed');  
    }
});

function scaleIt(proportion) {

    var factor = 'scale(' + proportion + ')';
    img.css({'-webkit-transform': factor, transform: factor});
}
});
```

Comment: you are awesome,

it shoudl first appear as zero width and hieght, and maximum width: 151px, max height: 500px.

The idea is to have a kind of zoom in effect :)

Thank you so much for your help !! really love it !

Comment: No problem, gonna look into it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Define a function and apply on scroll. Note that is passing `$(this)` refference to take the reference of the object (`window` in this case):

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
     yourFunction($(this));
});

function yourFunction($this) {
    scrollPosition = $this.scrollTop();
    if (scrollPosition >= 500) {
        // If the function is only supposed to fire once
        $this.off('scroll');
        var width = $('img').width();
        var height = $('img').height();
        $('img').width(0).height(0);
        var ratio = width/height;
        console.log(width,height);

  }

}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you,

I tried this but it doesn't seem to work :/ :/ Do you have any other suggestion by any chance ?

Comment: I put you on the direction to wrap into function something. If you have a fiddle reproducing the issue I can help you better

Comment: Hi, Thank you . .. I tried to wrap it into that function that you gived . . but no luck :/

Here is my fiddle if it helps . ..:

http://jsfiddle.net/mw73enz8/10/

Really appreciate your time Marcos !

Answer (score 0):

Your first code is already working for me.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var width = $('img').width();
    var height = $('img').height();

    $('img').width(0).height(0);

    var ratio = width/height;

    console.log(width,height);


$(window).on("scroll", function() {

    console.log(ratio);
    var w = $(document).scrollTop();    
        $("img").width(w*ratio).height(w)
});

});
</script>
```

I tried it on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ne4LyLbu/

Comment: Hi,

Yes this i working but i want this function to start only after 400px scroll down . ..  :( Do you have any idea by any chance please :) ?

Comment: I would just add a "if(w < 400) return;" after the line which begins with "var w =... ". This will always check if the scroll position is still below 400px and end the function there so that your width and height commands are not executed. But as I can see,  your problem is solved already.